# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: in Posting Json data to server Using get Method

Tags: android

```
11-30 10:34:05.747  21907-21951/info.androidhive.materialdesign E/log_tag﹕ Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 48:

http://bhaskarmart.com/api/values/savebill?data={userId:2,slotdatetime:21/11/2015%205:00%20PM,address:behind%20behind.%20fhif,total:350,orderdata:[{%22productid%22:%2226%22,%22productcount%22:%221%22}]%20
```

when I find index at 48 then I found this charcter { so can please tell me how to post Json data I have to Post this data:

```
{userId:2,slotdatetime:21/11/2015%205:00%20PM,address:behind%20behind.%20fhif,total:350,orderdata:[{"productid":"26","productcount":"1"}]}`
```

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment: dude, your problem is not clear. please make it more clear by adding text in question what you are trying to do and also share some part of code

Comment: Look am making JSon format data i have to Post some addiation data and when i try to post data to server then i am getting illegalstateException at index 48 when i found then it show { this

Comment: {userId:2,slotdatetime:21/11/2015%205:00%20PM,address:behind%20behind.%20fhif,total:350,orderdata:[{"productid":"26","productcount":"1"}]}  this data we have to post to server

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment: show your code what u are using for posting data on server

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/KK2PSRPaja2w8LLf4MvAwj  look this is code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK did look my code?

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment:see my answer and also because using `URLEncoder.encode` then i think no need to use `replace(" ", "%20")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is caused by :

```
response = HttpPost.getJSONfromURL(URLEncoder.encode(totaldata, "UTF-8"));
```

line because encoding url also with parameters. do it as:

```
String strUrl="http://bhaskarmart.com/api/values/savebill?data=";
String strJson="{"+ finalOrderdata +"}";
response = HttpPost.getJSONfromURL(strUrl+URLEncoder.encode(strJson, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data is not valid.

Below is valid JSON data.

Add double quote in Json key.

```
{
    "userId": 2,
    "slotdatetime": "21/11/2015%205:00%20PM",
    "address": "behind%20behind.%20fhif",
    "total": 350,
    "orderdata": [
        {
            "productid": "26",
            "productcount": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```